# how to use OpenSMPP

Tags: java, smpp

I wanted to know if anybody has an idea how to use opensmpp, I want to create a java program that connects through an smpp interface to send sms messages. If you can provide me with a guide and if there are any opensource applications that does the same thing out there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are referring to [Logica SMPP](http://opensmpp.logica.com/) implementation, perhaps you should look at the [test application](http://opensmpp.logica.com/CommonPart/Download/download2.html#javatest) which uses the API.

You could also look at two other libraries:

- [SMPP Sim](http://www.seleniumsoftware.com/downloads.html) - simulator tool for SMPP
- [SMPPAPI](http://smppapi.sourceforge.net/) - an alternate library for SMPP

Comment: i put the library,server and the test app in the same dir. double clicked the test app, and nothings happens. any help

Comment: this answer is no longer useful